# how to get the metadata of jsTree.

Tags: jquery, metadata, jstree

This is my code:

```
$("#demo1").jstree({
        "themes": {
            "theme": "default",
            "dots": true,
            "icons": true,
            "url": "static/themes/default/style.css"
        },
        "ui" : {
                // this makes the node with ID node_4 selected onload
                "initially_select" : [ location.hash.slice(1).split('@')[1]]
            },
        "json_data" : {
            "data" : [
                { 
                    "data" : "A node", 
                    "attr" : { "id" : "1" ,time:1321},
                    "callback":function(){alert('sss')},
                    "children" : [ 
                        {
                            "data" : "ttt node", 
                            "children" : [ "Child 1", "Child 2" ]   
                        }
                     ]
                },
                { 
                    "attr" : { "id" : "2" }, 
                    "data" : { 
                        "title" : "Long format demo", 
                        "attr" : { "href" : "#" } 
                    } 
                },
                {
                    "data" : "sss node", 
                    "attr" : { "id" : "3" },
                    "children" : [ 
                        {
                            "data" : "bbb node"
                        }
                        ,
                        {
                            "data" : "kkkk node", 
                            "attr" : { "id" : "11" },
                            "children" : [ 
                                {
                                    "data" : "oooo node", 
                                    "children" : [ "pppp", "nnnn" ] 
                                }
                             ]
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "data" : "wwqq node",
                    "attr" : { "id" : "4" },
                    "children" : [ "Child 1", "Child 2" ]   
                },
                {
                    "data" : "hhh node",
                    "attr" : { "id" : "5" },
                    "metadata ":"i am the metadata",
                    "children" : [ 
                            {
                            "data" : "A node", 
                            "children" : [ 
                                {
                                    "data" : "ttt node", 
                                    "children" : [ "Child 1", "Child 2" ]   
                                }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                            "data" : "bbb node"
                            }

                        ]   
                },
            ]
        },
        /*
        "sort":function (a, b) { 
            return this.get_text(a) < this.get_text(b) ? 1 : -1; 
            },
        ////*/
        "contextmenu":{
                "show_at_node":false,
                "items":{
                        //"ccp":false,
                        "sort" : {
                            // The item label
                            "label"             : "sort",
                            /* The function to execute upon a click
                            "action"            : function (obj) { 
                                                    var fn=function (a, b) {return this.get_text(a) < this.get_text(b) ? 1 : -1;}
                                                    this.changeSort(obj,fn);

                                                    },
                            //*/
                            // All below are optional 
                            "_disabled"         : false,        // clicking the item won't do a thing
                            "_class"            : "sort",   // class is applied to the item LI node
                            "separator_before"  : false,    // Insert a separator before the item
                            "separator_after"   : true,     // Insert a separator after the item
                            // false or string - if does not contain `/` - used as classname
                            "icon"              : false,
                            "submenu"           : { 
                                "name":{
                                        "label" : "name",
                                        "action": function (obj) { 
                                                        var fn=function (a, b) {return this.get_text(a) < this.get_text(b) ? 1 : -1;}
                                                        this.changeSort(obj,fn);
                                                    }
                                    },
                                "time":{
                                        "label" : "time",
                                        "action": function (obj) { 
                                                        var fn=function (a, b) {return this.get_text(a) < this.get_text(b) ? 1 : -1;}
                                                        this.changeSort(obj,fn);

                                                    }
                                    }
                                }
                        },
                        "icons":{
                            "label"             : "icons",
                            "action":function(obj){window.a=obj;},
                            "submenu"           : { 
                                "apple":{
                                        "label" : "apple",
                                        "action": function (obj) { 
                                                        this.set_theme('apple');
                                                    }
                                    },
                                "classic":{
                                        "label" : "classic",
                                        "action": function (obj) { 
                                                        this.set_theme('classic');
                                                    }
                                    },
                                "default":{
                                        "label" : "default",
                                        "action": function (obj) { 
                                                        this.set_theme('default');
                                                    }
                                    }
                                }

                        }
            }
        },
        "core" : { "initially_open" : [ ] },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data","crrm","ui","contextmenu","search","sort" ]
    })
    .bind("search.jstree", function (e, data) {
            alert("Found " + data.rslt.nodes.length + " nodes matching '" + data.rslt.str + "'.");
        });
```

i set the metadata:

```
"metadata ":"i am the metadata",
```

and want to get it when i right click,on the "contextmenu" :

```
"icons":{
                            "label"             : "icons",
                            "action":function(obj){console.log(this.data);},
```

I show this.data follow this [article](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data):

```
// the `metadata` property will be saved using the jQuery `data` function on the `li` node
    metadata : "a string, array, object, etc",
```

but I can't get it, what can I do?

Comment: Please consider moving the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7731120/466771 The current best answer is not correct (any more).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JsTree stores metadata with jQuery:

```
.data("jstree", "a string, array, object, etc")
```

To access this metadata use:

```
.data("jstree")
```

For example, once you pass some `DateTime` object in json format:

```
metadata : { lastModified : "/Date(1283198400000)/" }
```

Access it:

```
$.jstree
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
    alert( formatJsonDateTime( data.rslt.obj.data("jstree").lastModified ) );
});

function formatJsonDateTime(jsonDate) {
    var date = eval(jsonDate.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"));
    return date.format("M/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
};
```

Comment: This does NOT WORK any more.  Perhaps it did, but not with the most current version.  This works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7731120/466771

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer does not work with the latest version of jsTree.  Here's an updated example building upon the previous.

```
metadata : { lastModified : "/Date(1283198400000)/" }
```

Access the data:

```
$.jstree
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
    alert( data.rslt.obj.data("lastModified") );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can get the full node by using get_node function from jstree like

`var node = $(container).jstree().get_node("node_id");`

then you can access the data from

`node.original.metadata`

Answer (score 0):

None of those solutions worked for me. What did is the following:

```
alert(data.rslt.obj.data()[0].lastModified)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with jstree 1.0-rc3, dated 2011-02-09. First of all, I found that assigning a string to metadata like this `"metadata ":"i am the metadata"` didn't work. It had to be a JSON object.  My tree is representing a directory structure starting from the root folder "exercises" so I want each node to store the path on the server where the directory structure is stored.  The server sends out JSON data (simplified for clarity) like this:

```
[
    {
        "data":"Book1",
        "metadata":{"path":"exercises\/Book1"},
    },
    {
        "data":"vocabulary",
        "metadata":{"path":"exercises\/vocabulary"}
    }
]
```

I use the path value from the metadata to build the correct URL for the AJAX request sent when you open a folder that contains other folders or files.  The url property of the ajax property used to configure the tree looks like this:

```
"url": function (node) {
    var path = "",
    url = "/tree_service/tree/format/json?path=";
    if(node === -1){
        url += "exercises";
    }
    else{
        path = encodeURIComponent(node.data().path);
        url += path;
    }
    return url;
}
```

As promised by the documentation, we can use the data() function on the node passed to the url function and lurking in the object returned is the path property.