# can the popular javascript tree views (jstree, dynatree...) be setup to read data from an adjacency model?

Tags: json, linq, treeview, jstree, dynatree

can the popular javascript tree views (jstree, dynatree...) be setup to read data from an adjacency model?
say I have a table with classId, ClassName,ClassType,ParentClassId how can i fetch data for say the dynatree? considering the json expected by dyna tree should something like below

```
        {title: "Class1"},
        {title: "Class2", isFolder: true,
            children: [
                {title: "Class4"},
                {title: "Class5"}
            ]
        },
        {title: "Class3"}
```

I am using an asp.net asmx web service with linq to sql at the backend

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8087897/250422

Comment: Radek, so theres no need to load the child nodes at 1st load - nice elegant approach - makes it much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you have to do to have nodes loaded on demand is to add "state" : "closed" to the nodes whose child nodes are going to be loaded on demand.

You can have all your necessary attributes `classId, ClassName,ClassType,ParentClassId` attached to the node so then you can pass it through via ajax. 
ur code

```
"json_data": {
      //elements to be displayed on the first load
      //everything with state = closed will be populated via ajax. 
      //         Note the ajax arguments

    "data": [{"data":'Class 1',
              "attr":{"id":'kit1',
                      "ClassName":"ClassName",
                      "classId":"classId"},
              "state" : "closed"},
             {"data":'Class 2',
              "attr":{"id":'kit2',
                      "ClassName":"ClassName",
                      "classId":"classId"},
              "state" : "closed"}
            ],
    "ajax" : {
        url : "http://localhost/introspection/introspection/product",
        data : function(n) {
                 return {
                   "classId":$.trim(n.attr('classId')),
                   "ClassName":$.trim(n.attr('ClassName')),
                 }
               }
    }
 }
```