# JsTree and JSON - pull data from url

Tags: jquery, json, jstree

I have a site with a JStree.  It pulls its data from a JSON object.  When you click on a JsTree node, it loads the appropriate DB data, which is converted JSON and then shown.

The thing is, now we want to have URLs that correspond to whats happening on the page.  Because everything is happening with AJAX, the URL is staying the same.

So when someone clicks on the Category Wordpress-> Business -> Financial, it'd be great if the URL could change to www.domain.com/wordpress/business/financial, and have the params pulled from the URL< to get the the appropriate database data, based on those params.

Is this possible?  And is it possible to do this without page reloads?  As in, just update the address bar, and JQuery can oull the params and get the corresponding data?

I know this is a broad question, but I'm not even sure really where to start

Comment: You cannot programatically change the url to `www.domain.com/wordpress/business/financial` unless you do it it in HTML5.

Comment: really?  You can't with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to tweak the url function to work with parent nodes as well. Below code will give you an idea how to solve you question. Credit goes to @Christian Waidner - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8094199/250422

I haven't tested the code ...

```
        "ajax" : {
            "type": 'GET',
            "url": function (node) {
                var nodeId = "";
                var url = "http://www.domain.com/wordpress/";
                if (node != -1){
                    nodeName = node.attr('name');

                    url = url + nodeName;
                }

                return url;
            },
            "success": function (new_data) {
                return new_data;
            }
```

Comment: hm, let me try this out and see how it goes