# jsTree: how to retrieve 'metadata'?

Tags: jquery-plugins, metadata, jstree

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604790/how-to-get-the-metadata-of-jstree) example, but there is still a problem - I could not get 'metadata' value. Could somebody show one more example?

Answer (score 0):

That example is working fine for me with version 1.0-rc3

Here's another:

```
{
    'attr': {'id': 'example1'},
    'data': {
        'attr': {
            'href': '#'
        },
        'title': 'Example'
    },
    'metadata': {
        'hello': 'world'
    }
}
```

And to retrieve the metadata:

```
$(node).data('hello'); // world
```